# JAVA how to randomise an operation?

Tags: java, operation

I'm writing a program that creates random calculations to be solved, aimed at primary school kids.

I want to randomise an operation type, eg. +, -, *, / for various difficulty of questions. Currently I am using a switch statement on a randomised integer to return an operation in string form. However when I wish to perform checks to validate correct user input:

```
if((randNumOne randOperation randNumTwo) > (randNumThree randOperationTwo randNumFour))
```

This obviously does not work however I cannot figure out how to implement the random operation in a statement to check user input, how would I go about doing so?

Comment: If `random` is an object of class `Random`, you could write `"+-*/".charAt(random.nextInt(4))` but you'll still need a `switch` statement to actually evaluate the result.  Best to do this anyway, because you probably don't want things like division problems with non-integer answers.

Answer (score 0):

Often, when you have a switch statement it is a sign that what you really need is an array of objects that implement a particular interface.  Instead of using the switch statement, you use the random integer as an index into the array, and use the object to get the different behavior you want.

You might have an interface:

```
string getOperatorName(); // Different instances return "+", "-", "*"...
double evaluateOperator(double operanda, double operandb); // Different instances implement +, -, *
```

Comment: Better, an enum for the operators, with an evaluate method.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making a static function (wherever it fits) which takes two arguments (I'm assuming you'll only use binary operations here) and returns a result of a random (again, binary) operation over given two arguments? Of course, it would have to have some type of checking for division by zero (just letting exceptions unhandled or even handled isn't good in this case).